# How to add dynamic layout in existing layout ( Android, JSON )

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I have an app in which I am showing data from JSON. I am displaying data in a dynamic textview on the right and left side of the relative layout. Now I want to add this layout in an existing layout so that I can apply an `OnClickListener` on the textview. Right now I am getting data into a string and then setting that string into static textviews in the left and right side of the layout.

**How would it be possible to generate textview dynamically on the basis of number of data I am getting from JSON ?**

```
 for (Region object : temp.phonelist.regionList)

            {
                if (object.getCCInfoShortDesc() != null ||  !(object.getCCInfoShortDesc().equals(null)))
                {
                    Log.i("nullexception", "nullexception");

                    holder.tvDescription.setText(object.getCCInfoShortDesc());
                    holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    Log.i("nullexception1", "nullexception1");
                    holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                leftContent += object.getCCInfoLeft() + ":" + "\n";
                rightContent += object.getCCInfoRight()  + "\n";

            }
            Log.i("lefftcontent", leftContent);
            Log.i("rightcontent", rightContent);

            if (leftContent != null) {
                holder.tvData2.setText(leftContent);
                holder.tvData2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } 
            if (rightContent != null) {
                holder.tvData1.setText(rightContent);
                holder.tvData1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
How it is possible to genrate textview dynamically 
on the basis of number of data i am getting from json.
```

You need to create `TextView` and add it to the `parent layout` each time you **iterate** on the forloop. So you will have textView for each of the element of the `temp.phonelist.regionList`

**sample:**

```
 for (Region object : temp.phonelist.regionList)
 {
     TextView tx = new TextView(context); //creating a new instance if textview
     //yourstuff goes here
     tx.setText(text_you_want);
     yourView.addView(tx); //this is to add the textView on each iteration

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way..

```
  final int Count = < Number of TextViews>; // total number of textviews to add

   final TextView[] TextViewsARR = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

   for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
   // create a new textview
   final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

   // set some properties of rowTextView or something
   rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

   // add the textview to the linearlayout
   myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

  // save a reference to the textview for later
    TextViewsARR [i] = rowTextView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- I have a sample below that generates a `checkbox` dynamically, If you
  observe i am generating the `checkbox` based on the `cursor count`.
  You can adapt this saple to your needs
- Instead of `checkbox` use a `texview`
- Give any layout like `linear`, `relative` etc and generate views
  `dynamically`

---

```
private CheckBox chkBoxMealType[] = null;

mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT meal_type_id,meal_type_name FROM meal_type_mas", null);

            if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    if(chkBoxMealTypeCnt==0){
                        chkBoxMealType=new CheckBox[mCursor.getCount()];
                    }
                    //create a general view for checkbox
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt]= new CheckBox(getActivity());
                    //Create params for veg-checkbox
                    //Reason:: we don't need to worry about the data exist in cuisine_type_mas table
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.searchGoldLight));
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt].setTag(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(meal_type_mas.COLUMN_MEAL_TYPE_ID)));
                    chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt].setText(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(meal_type_mas.COLUMN_MEAL_TYPE_NAME))));
                    mealTypeContainer.addView(chkBoxMealType[chkBoxMealTypeCnt]);
                    //since cursor count starts from 0 last count must be allowed
                    chkBoxMealTypeCnt++;

                }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
                Log.d("", "");
            }
```

---

### [I have another sample..... Download this project(Click Here) and run in your editor](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvfhmr2zq4d0ao1/DynamicViews.rar)

**Snapshot**::

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add a View in your layout ... Like you may try using LinearLayout or HorizontalLayout ... and then attach/add your dynamic textview to that layout.

Pragmatically you may try like this

```
packageButtons = new ArrayList<TextView>(); // Create your textview arraylist like this
        for(int a = 0; a < your_text_view_from_json.size(); a++){

               final TextView rowTextView;
               rowTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
               rowTextView.setText(taxi_type_spin.get(a).taxi_type);
               rowTextView.setTextSize(15);
               rowTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
               //rowTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);      
               packageButtons.add(rowTextView);
               rowTextView.setLayoutParams(lparam);
               rowTextView.setId(a);
               final int b = a;
               // get value of clicked item over here .. 

               rowTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button btn = (Button)v;
                    String get_value = btn.getText().toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button name is : " + get_value + " AND ID IS : " + rowTextView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(taxi_type_spin.get(b).taxi_type.equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.Hourly_Package))
                    {
                        setTaxiType(rowTextView.getId(),true);
                        ll_spin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setTaxiType(rowTextView.getId(),false);
                        ll_spin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    setSelectedButtonColor(b);

                }
            });

              // add the textview to the linearlayout
              myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
```

**NOTE** rowTextView .. this is your default view attached to your XML file

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setLayout(LinearLayout llayout,
        final ArrayList<String> items) {

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout row = null;
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        row = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.custom_item,
                null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);                 

        llayout.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ArrayList, because the class java.util.ArrayList provides resizable-array, which means that items can be added and removed from the list dynamically.

and get value from ArrayList something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)
        {             
           textName.setText(object.getName());             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution do this way,Take one Layout(Linear or Relative) and add control dynamically....

```
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

            TextView txtDemo = new TextView(getActivity());
            txtDemo .setTextSize(16);
            txtDemo .setLayoutParams(lp);
            txtDemo .setId(i);
            lp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
            txtDemo .setPadding(20, 10, 10, 10);
            txtDemo .setText("Text View"+ i);
            linearlayout.addView(txtDemo );

        }
    }
```